# Proxied POCO like Self-tracking entities

Tags: .net, entity-framework

As I understand, Proxied POCO objects can track changes only being attached to ObjectContext. On the contrary STE tracks changes even being detached. I am curious why there is no support for a POCO proxy which will implement STE behaviour internally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take this only as my personal opinion.

There are no "self tracking proxies" because for current implementation it would nor make sense. Why:

- Self tracking entities were developed to support change set scenarios over web services where entity is able to track changes on the client side, client will pass these changes back to service and entity will apply changes back to a new instance of the context.
- To make this work client and service must share implementation of self tracking entities.

That is supposed usage of STEs. In any other scenario they don't have too much sense

- In WinForms / WPF / Service application directly accessing EF you don't need them and it is generally a bad scenario to use them because you can use attached entities directly.
- In Web application you don't want them because it would require storing them either serialized in page (= same as view state) or in session / cache. First scenario is design approach which is dead for many years and you should simply not use it and second should be avoided as much as possible.

So where do you see the usage of "self tracking proxies"? Do you want to use them instead of STEs? Why? And more importantly how? Main advantage of STEs implementation is that they are serializable whereas dynamically created proxies are not! If you check how serialization over web services (WCF) work you will see that all serializable types passed through services must be know when the service is started. Otherwise only basic unproxied will be exposed.

Comment: I would use them even in desktop applications and Web. There are two points which I don't like working with attached entities. 1. Changes saving implicitness. If I modified several entities, all of them will be saved. But what if I want to save only one of them? In STE I can explicitly tell to update one entity. 2. In cases of exceptions which are catched ObjectContext may be in inconsistent state. And when I call SaveChanges, this inconsistancy will go to database. It is not so in STE approach.

Comment: In such case you are simply not using EF as supposed - you are not using context as unit of work otherwise you would never find scenario where you need to save only subset of modifications and because of that you are looking for hacks.

Comment: My fault. I didn't want to say my primary goal is to save a subset of modifications. I am just not comfortable with the fact that any entity property modification will go to database when I call SaveChanges. I would prefer to explicitly mark entities for update calling _myRepository.Update(entity)

Comment: But that is simply not how ORM (not only EF) behaves. If you want selective updates you must write your application to use separate context instance for each updatable set.

Comment: That is how I use it now with STE. And really I like it. It is explicit, I have no problems with inconsistent ObjectContext in case of exceptions, etc. But I want the same behaviour with POCO, that's why I made this question

Comment: And what would be the difference in having self tracking implemented as proxy instead of directly in class? Except that it will be much less visible and harcoded whereas in STEs you can modify it to your actual needs. And you made question to the wrong site. This site is about solving existing problems not about discussion subjective ideas why is something not implemented. If you want to have that implemented go to [Uses Voice](http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-ado-net-entity-framework-ef-feature-suggestions) and make a suggestion or go to MSDN forum and ask why it is not implemented yet.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1284/discussion-between-idsa-and-ladislav-mrnka)